# how to get element from databind foreach javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

my question why when I write ClassName[1] give me undefined ?
my code:

```
    <select id="ClassNameEdit" class=" form-control" data-bind="foreach:ClassData">

              <option data-bind="text:ClassName,value:ClassId, name:ClassId"></option>

            </select>
  <script>
let a= document.getElementById('ClassNameEdit').children
console.log(a.item(1))

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that element with plain Javascript you would have to do:

```
let a = document.getElementById('ClassNameEdit').children;
console.log("my element = ", a.item(0));
```

The first element, would start with the index of 0 not 1.

Comment: it give me null

Comment: @alaakaheel can u share a jsfiddle?

Comment: @alaakaheel  https://jsfiddle.net/Ldh5g2oe/ look at the console, the element gets logged